# Access shadow DOM from Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, shadow-dom, custom-component

I'm currently working on a custom component with Vue3. I defined it like:

```js
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue';
import Panel from '~/components/panel_custom/Panel.ce.vue';

const CustomElement = defineCustomElement(Panel);
window.customElements.define('panel-custom', CustomElement);
```

Now I'm trying to access the shadowRoot to get some scroll-to-bottom function working.

How would I get access to the element to call the shadowRoot from Like: `element.shadowRoot;`?

I don't find anything in the vue documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From within the Vue component, the shadow root is the parent node, so you could access it via `this.$el.parentNode`:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    // assuming this Vue component is mounted as a custom element
    // via `defineCustomElement()` and `window.customElements.define()`
    console.log({ shadowRoot: this.$el.parentNode })
  }
}
```

Or you can query the document for the custom element, and access the `shadowRoot` property directly from the reference. The following example assumes the custom element exists in the light DOM at the time of query, and not within the shadow DOM. `document.querySelector()` does not pierce the shadow DOM, so if the element is within another custom element with a [closed-mode shadow root](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#closed), the query will return `undefined`.

```js
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

const CustomElement = defineCustomElement(HelloWorld)
window.customElements.define('hello-world', CustomElement)

// assume element is in light DOM
const el = document.querySelector('hello-world')
console.log({ shadowRoot: el?.shadowRoot })
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-custom-element-shadowroot?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: If I use it in my main.js like you mentioned, it's getting me `undefined`. 
The first way with the mounted hook works, tho. Is there a way to also get this inside the composition API with setup?

Comment: The `main.js` example assumes `hello-world` exists in the document at the time of the query. If it's `undefined` for you, that means the element is either not in the document, or is in the shadow DOM (e.g., contained in another custom element).

Comment: Within the Composition API, you can access the component's root element by applying a template ref on the root element.